# can you guys help me with the order for the dom?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with undefined property
I added the first part of my js I have a document.readystate witch suppose to help with the Dom not reading fills but I still get undefined

```js
if (document.readyState == `loading`) {
  document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, ready);
} else {
  ready
}

function ready() {
  var hiddentwo = document.getElementById(`sectiontop`)
  var hidden = document.getElementById(`sectionone`)
  var hiddentwo = document.getElementById(`sectiontop`)
  console.log(hiddentwo)
  const openModal = function() {
    hidden.classList.remove(`hidesection`);
  };
  const closeModal = function() {
    hidden.classList.add('hidden');
  };
  const closeModal1 = function() {
    hiddentwo.classlist.remove(`hidesection1`)


  };

  const closeModal11 = function() {
    hiddentwo.classlist.add(`hidesection1`)


  };
  window.onload = function() {
    hiddentwo.classlist.remove('hidesection1')
  };

};
```

```css
.hidesection1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="sectiontop" class="hidesection1">
```

Comment: _What_ is `undefined`? Elements don’t have a property called `classlist`; you mean [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Further, is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: please help been stuck for 5 hours come on

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I meant quotation marks. Seemed lack of quotes.

Comment: @connexo i did what you said but still the error still there

Comment: @connexo i dont understand how readystate works i just was following a tutorial and told me to do that in the beginning of the script

Comment: @s.kuznetsov No, the quotes weren’t lacking. The quotes are correct.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Comment: You are defining `hiddenone` twice.

Comment: @connexo ty for telling but im not using hiddeone in my code i need to delete that

Comment: @37bandiko You still define `hiddentwo` twice, though.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I also meant that the quotes are correct. At first it seemed to me that there were no quotes at all.

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, please comment accordingly. If yes, please pick an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this block in your code:

```js
if  (document.readyState == `loading`)
    {document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`,ready);}
else{ready}
```

and replace it with either

```js
document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, ready);
```

or use the [ready state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) change event (which requires checking the state inside your `ready`  function):

```js
document.addEventListener(`readystatechange`, ready);

// and in ready():
function ready() {
    if (document.readyState === 'interactive') {
        // your code from ready function body here
    }
};
```

You always use either method, never both.

Answer (score 0):

as @Sebastian Simon and @ conexo pointed out `hiddentwo.classlist.remove` must be `hiddentwo.classList.remove.` Case matters in Javascript.